# Understanding addView functioning

Tags: android, button, view

When I use Java code to dynamically add a button to an Android layout I first have to declare a local copy of the button similar to this:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

Then there is some typical code as follows (but varies with the application):

```
// sets button width and height
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bparms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w, h); 
// sets button left and top position inside layout
bparms.setMargins(l, t, 0, 0);
```

This may be followed by setting other button properties such as text, background etc. Finally the button gets added to the parent layout as follows:

```
// add the dynamic button to the keypad view
kpad.addView(btn, bparms);
```

Here is my question. Does the layout receiving the button make a copy of the locally created dynamic button? Or does it just take a reference to the that created button leaving the originally created object intact?

Comment: you are able to get the android source code and see what the Android code does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, there is an `addInArray` method of `ViewGroup` class, and it just takes a reference of the child view and adds it to `children` array:

```
private void addInArray(View child, int index) {
    View[] children = mChildren;
    final int count = mChildrenCount;
    final int size = children.length;
    if (index == count) {
        if (size == count) {
            mChildren = new View[size + ARRAY_CAPACITY_INCREMENT];
            System.arraycopy(children, 0, mChildren, 0, size);
            children = mChildren;
        }
        children[mChildrenCount++] = child;
    } else if (index < count) {
        if (size == count) {
            mChildren = new View[size + ARRAY_CAPACITY_INCREMENT];
            System.arraycopy(children, 0, mChildren, 0, index);
            System.arraycopy(children, index, mChildren, index + 1, count - index);
            children = mChildren;
        } else {
            System.arraycopy(children, index, children, index + 1, count - index);
        }
        children[index] = child;
        mChildrenCount++;
        if (mLastTouchDownIndex >= index) {
            mLastTouchDownIndex++;
        }
    } else {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index=" + index + " count=" + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, java is working with references. So your object will not be cloned, you just give a reference of the object to the layout. Also, whenever you receive the object, e.g. by iteration over all views in the layout programmatically, you will also only receive a reference to the object. Cloning may be possible, when you e.g. assign a new variable (with a new memory position).